# DXA flagged with Path Traversal Vulenerability

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

How can we resolve a path traversal vulnerability that has been flagged in our DXA code? Any insights or solutions on how take to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.

> URI: HEAD /path/to/file/sample.jpg
>
> which was accessed within the following code:

```
com.sdl.dxa.tridion.content.GenericStaticContentResolver#getStaticContentFileByPath(), line 78
```

Comment: can you please share the Tridion and DXA version and what web server and operating system your DXA is  currently running on. I see your tag that you are using dxa-java.

Comment: Tridon Site 9.5, DXA version:2.2.28 ,  Running on docker conainer based on openjdk:8 image(alpine3.5 and Java 8u121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path Traversal security vulnerability. This issue has been fixed. (DXA 2.2.32 is available from Maven Central).

https://github.com/RWS/dxa-web-application-java/commit/35a66184b19c106e79dbeb63c906b9525a2f1796